# Stop process if there is an error in the constructor

Tags: c++, constructor

In a utility class file, I want to open a file to read or write it.
If I can't open it, I don't want to continue the process.

```
FileUtility::FileUtility(const char *fileName) {
  ifstream in_stream;
  in_stream.open(filename);
}

FileUtility fu = FileUtility("bob.txt");
fu.read();
fu.write();
```

File `bob.txt` doesn't exist, so I don't want method to read and write.

Is there a clean way to do it?

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/exceptions

Comment: if you don't want to use an exception you could make a loaded variable within the class that you can check from the main.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are generally four ways error state can be communicated from a callee to a caller:

**1. Direct return value (return code or OUT parameter).**

A return code is not possible for a constructor call, although an OUT parameter is. However, it's somewhat invasive to require every function to provide its return code or an OUT parameter for this purpose, so I don't like this solution in general, although it is certainly heavily used in various libraries and APIs. You could use this approach by adding a pointer or reference parameter to your constructor, to which the caller could provide the address of some local error variable, into which the constructor could store a possible return value. I don't recommend this.

**2. Exceptions.**

There is a somewhat polarized debate on the pros and cons of exceptions, in both C++ code and in other languages. I may take some downvotes for saying this, but my personal opinion is that exceptions should be avoided like the plague. See http://www.joelonsoftware.com/items/2003/10/13.html for someone who shares my view. But this is a workable solution if you're so inclined. See @Brian's answer for a good demonstration of this solution.

**3. Object attribute.**

The `std::ifstream` object actually does this, so you can leverage that. (Actually, from your example code, you define your `std::ifstream` as a local variable in the constructor, which implies it won't persist after the call, but since you call some kind of `read()` and `write()` methods on the constructed object, that implies that you *do* persist it after the call, so I'm going to assume the latter is the correct inference.) You can leverage that, by calling [`std::ifstream::is_open()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/fstream/ifstream/is_open/). If you want to maintain encapsulation of the `std::ifstream`, you can define your own `is_open()` equivalent on `FileUtility` that will simply return `in_stream.is_open();`, again, assuming it is retained as an attribute on your `FileUtility` class.

```
struct FileUtility {
    ifstream ifs;
    FileUtility(const char* fileName);
    bool is_open(void) const;
};

FileUtility::FileUtility(const char* fileName) { ifs.open(fileName); }
bool FileUtility::is_open(void) const { return ifs.is_open(); }

FileUtility fu = FileUtility("bob.txt");
if (!fu.is_open()) return 1;
```

Alternatively, you could create a whole new error state layer just for the `FileUtility` class, and propagate the `std::ifstream` error through that. For example:

```
struct FileUtility {
    static const int ERROR_NONE = 0;
    static const int ERROR_BADFILE = 1;
    ifstream ifs;
    int error;
    FileUtility(const char* fileName);
};

FileUtility::FileUtility(const char* fileName) : error(ERROR_NONE) {
    ifs.open(fileName);
    if (!ifs.is_open()) { error = ERROR_BADFILE; return; }
}

FileUtility fu = FileUtility("bob.txt");
if (fu.error != FileUtility::ERROR_NONE) return 1;
```

These are reasonable solutions.

**4. Global error state.**

I wouldn't be surprised if some programmers were to respond with a "that sounds like a bad idea" reaction to this possible solution, but the truth is that many extremely successful and prominent code bases use this solution for communicating error state. Perhaps the best examples are the [`errno`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/errno.3.html) variable used by the C Standard Library (although it should be mentioned that `errno` sort of works in conjunction with direct return codes), and the [`GetLastError()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/windows/desktop/ms679360(v=vs.85).aspx) system used by the Windows C API. I suppose some might argue that that's really the "C approach", and exceptions are the "C++ approach", but again, I avoid exceptions like the plague.

As an aside, multithreadedness is not a problem for this solution, because `errno` and `GetLastError()` both use thread-local error state, rather than true global error state.

I like this solution best, because it's simple, extremely uninvasive, and can easily be reused by different code bases, provided of course that you define the error framework (basically the thread-local variable and possibly the `ERROR_NONE` macro/global; see below) in its own library, in which case your code gains a consistency when it comes to error handling.

Example:

```
#define ERROR_NONE 0
thread_local int error = ERROR_NONE;

struct FileUtility {
    static const int ERROR_BADFILE = 1;
    ifstream ifs;
    FileUtility(const char* fileName);
};

FileUtility::FileUtility(const char* fileName) {
    ifs.open(fileName);
    if (!ifs.is_open()) { error = ERROR_BADFILE; return; }
}

FileUtility fu = FileUtility("bob.txt");
if (error != ERROR_NONE) return 1;
```

This is the solution I'd recommend; otherwise I'd go with an object attribute solution.

Answer (score 4):

When construction of an object fails in C++, you should throw an exception, or propagate the exception from the failed construction of the subobject.

```
FileUtility(const char* filename) {
    std::ifstream in_stream;
    in_stream.exceptions(std::ios_base::failbit);
    in_stream.open(filename); // will throw if file can't be opened
}
```

In the calling code you can choose to handle the exception:

```
try {
    FileUtility fu = FileUtility("bob.txt");
} catch (std::ios_base::failure) {
    printf("Failed to open bob.txt\n");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
// do other stuff
```

Or, if you don't catch the exception, the runtime will just call `std::terminate()`, which will print out its own error message, which may or may not be helpful:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::ios_base::failure'
  what():  basic_ios::clear
Aborted
```